# Alarm button click

Tags: android, android-alarms

When I click on start button alarm starts and when I click on stop, it stops but when I click on start again, alarm won't start. Kindly help me with it. Here's the code:

```
public class alarm : Activity
{
    protected MediaPlayer _player;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        _player = MediaPlayer.Create (this,Resource.Raw.police_alarm);
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.alarm);
        Button start = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.Start_ALarm);
        start.Click += delegate {
            _player.Start ();


        };
        Button stop = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.Stop_ALarm);
        stop.Click += delegate {
            _player.Stop ();
        };
        //  FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.Start_ALarm).Click+=Start_alarm_click;
        //FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.Stop_ALarm).Click += Stop_alarm_click;

        // Create your application here
    }
    //FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.Start_ALarm).Click+=Start_alarm_click;
    public void Start_alarm_click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        _player.Start ();

    } 
    public void Stop_alarm_click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        _player.Stop ();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html):

> Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until prepare()
>   or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object to the
>   Prepared state again.

This suggests you should call

```
_player.prepare();
```

before trying to start it.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing the MediaPlayer should be done before the onCreate method.Otherwise when you click on stop the player object becomes null.Therefore you can initialize it right in the place of declaration here goes the code 
_player = MediaPlayer.Create (this,Resource.Raw.police_alarm);